# Regex woes with Subprocess output

Tags: python, regex

Im trying to match IP and MAC address from `subprocess` output, but it seems I have two issues (that I can see). The regx isn't very good as its missing some items and the other issue being that, for some reason OS X does not produce the correct MAC address output for the `arp -a` command.

I hate regx :(, I did start out using `socket.inet_aton()` to validate the ip addresses but iterating each line and trying to match regx with mac and validate using the `socket.inet_aton(addr)` was not particularly usable. So decided to go with regx on both counts.

I understand why the incorrect formatted output is not being matched (MAC) and that issue I will try address elsewhere but I can not work out why the correctly formatted output is not being matched. Have I mentioned i hate regx ? :)

**Update**

I did not notice the single digit in the following line initially `? (192.168.1.74) at fc:75:16:3:d0:2a on en0 ifscope [ethernet] # Not missing anything but does not match` so it seems my problem is more OSx not printing the MACs out correctly. It looks to be leaving off the first digit of a segment if it is a `0` for some reason. So I will need to add a `0` to the front of any single digit segment found to resolve my problem (until i work out why its doing this in the first place. Testing on other systems does not produce this single digit segment in the mac address.

**Output of script**

```
? (192.168.1.74) at fc:75:16:3:d0:2a on en0 ifscope [ethernet] # Not missing anything but does not match
192.168.1.74
? (192.168.1.115) at 28:32:c5:f1:eb:9e on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
192.168.1.115
28:32:c5:f1:eb:9e
? (192.168.1.126) at 0:c:29:30:a1:c9 on en0 ifscope [ethernet] #Notice the misson 0 ?
192.168.1.126
gateway.home (192.168.1.254) at f4:55:9c:62:8a:cc on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
192.168.1.254
f4:55:9c:62:8a:cc
? (192.168.1.255) at ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
192.168.1.255
ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
? (192.168.7.1) at 0:50:56:c0:0:8 on vmnet8 ifscope permanent [ethernet] #Notice the misson 0 ?
192.168.7.1
? (192.168.194.1) at 0:50:56:c0:0:1 on vmnet1 ifscope permanent [ethernet] #Notice the misson 0 ?
192.168.194.1
```

**Script**

```
cmd="arp -a"
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output, errrors = process.communicate()

for line in output.split("\n"):
    print line
    for data in line.split(' '):
        data = data.translate(None, '()')
        mac = re.match("^([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})$", data)
        if mac:
            print mac.group()
        ip = re.match("^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$", data)
        if ip:
            print ip.group()
```

Comment: Your regex is assuming 2 hexadecimal digits. Change `[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}` to `[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,2}`, and it should work.

Comment: Yes im aware its looking for 2 digits, I dont know of any MAC addresses that only have 1. I didnt notice the MAC in the first line in the output above had 1 digit further along. By the looks of it OSx doesnt print them out correctly in the first place. So it seems I will need to add a `0` to any 1 digit findings (looks like it leaves off the first `0` if its the first digit of the segment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MAC address regex (as pointed out by @nhahtdh) does not consider single digit (or letter) segment, I've also used a single regex for both (to avoid a loop and reduce the code).

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess
import re

cmd = "arp -a"
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output, errors = process.communicate()

for line in output.split("\n"):
    if line and not line.isspace():
        print "line ->", line
        regex = re.match("(?i).*?(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}).*?((?:[0-9A-F]{1,2}[:]){5}(?:[0-9A-F]{1,2}))", line)
        print "ip  ->", regex.group(1)
        print "mac ->", re.sub('(^[^:](?=:)|(?<=:)[^:](?=:)|(?<=:)[^:]$)', '0\\1', regex.group(2))
```

Comment: arr yes that is a better way to handle the regx. Thank you, once ive worked out how to add the missing `0` to each single digit segment ill use the above example of regex.

Comment: @iNoob i've edited the answer to fill single section of the mac address with zeros (if are composed of single char)

Comment: lol thank you, i was taking a different approach but again yours is better.

Comment: @iNoob I don't know if it's better (you can otherwise solve splitting the MAC address by ``':'`` and processing each element). Surely it's more ugly to see for a regex-hater :P

Comment: I only hate it because mine never works correctly lol thank again

Answer (score 0):

The currently accepted answer is overly complex. There's no need to split the string. The issue you're running into is the fact that `^` and `$` match the start/end of the string not a line. To make them match the ends of the line just pass `re.MULTILINE` to the compile flags.

Using your script from above, it would simply be:

```
cmd="arp -a"
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output, errrors = process.communicate()
mac_matcher = re.compile("^([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})$", re.M)
ip_matcher = re.compile("^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$", re.M)
# I'm using search here to just get the first value, but you can iterate instead
mac = mac_matcher.search(output)
ip = ip_matcher.search(output)
```