# error when trying to regex python3 subprocess command output

Tags: python, regex

I've been banging my head against a wall here...

I want to run a particular cli command from within a python script and then regex it's output. But I get the following error:

```
"File "speedtestcork.py", line 18, in regex_speedtest
    for line in data.split("\n"):
TypeError: Type str doesn't support the buffer API"
```

Here's my short code:

```
import time
import re
import speedtest_cli
import subprocess



def regex_speedtest(data):
        #output, errors = data.communicate()
        #output1 = str(output)
        Down_Regex = re.compile(r'(Download:).(\d+\.\d+).(Mbit/s)')
        Up_Regex = re.compile(r'(Upload:).(\d+\.\d+).(Mbit/s)')

        for line in data.split("\n"):          # code seems to break at this line.
                print(line)
                #Downmatch = Down_Regex.search(line)
                #Upmatch = Up_Regex.search(line)
        #return (Downmatch.group(2), Upmatch.group(2))



while True:
        now = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S %d %m %Y")
        process = subprocess.Popen(["speedtest-cli", "--server", "2432"], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        output, errors = process.communicate()
        down, up = regex_speedtest(output)
```

This should be simple to debug but I cannot find the solution.

Used the following post but still cannot resolve:

[Regex woes with Subprocess output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33013183/regex-woes-with-subprocess-output)

Thanks in advance,

Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python3 [`Popen.communicate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) returns `bytes`, while `regex_speedtest` expects `str` input.

Here's an updated version:

```
def regex_speedtest(data):
    Down_Regex = re.compile(rb'(Download:).(\d+\.\d+).(Mbit/s)')
    Up_Regex = re.compile(rb'(Upload:).(\d+\.\d+).(Mbit/s)')

    for line in data.splitlines():   
        print(line)
```

I've changed the `r` prefix to `rb`, which transforms string literals into byte literals and replaced `split("\n")` call with `splitlines`, since this works for both `str` and `bytes`.

**Update**: as noted by Duncan in the comments, replacing `"\n"` with `b"\n"` in the `split` call would work just as well.

Comment: or you could use `data.split(b'\n')` as the problem was simply the mixing of `str` and `bytes` in the `split` call.

Comment: The regex matches would've failed as well, try `re.compile("foo").search(b"foo")`.

Comment: Yes, I wasn't complaining about that part of your answer, just that you implied that `.split()` wouldn't work for bytes when in fact it does. (Not that there is anything wrong with using `.splitlines()` either).

Comment: Thanks guys, my first ever post here, well impressed with the response time and knowledge :) Solving this has highlighted another issue: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "speedtestcork.py", line 37, in <module>
    down, up = regex_speedtest(output)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: This might indicate that you don't return anything from `regex_speedtest`, which makes the unpacking fail.

Comment: @SergeiLebedev Thanks, yeah regex isn't matching but I don't understand why: Down_Regex = re.compile(rb'(Download:).(\d+\.\d+).(Mbit/s)')                                                                               Downmatch = Down_Regex.search(line)